# Date format issue in outlook while to excel-outlook automation

Tags: datetime, excel, outlook-2007, vba

I have exported email mesages to excel by using a macro. By using `Mid` function I have found the date in the email, but it's not formated as a date.

For example `Thursday, January 12, 2012 8:30 AM` This date is text, not a formated date. How do I format that as a date?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to take out "Thursday, " bit first.  And then use `CDate`.  This Should Work

```
DateStr = "Thursday, January 12, 2012 8:30 AM"
DateStr = Mid(DateStr, InStr(1, DateStr, ", ") + 1)
DateVal = CDate(DateStr)
```

Comment: I think you are correct. I misread the question. +1 for reading carefully.

Comment: @JP. I have tried deleting one of my answers in the past but all I was allowed to do was vote to delete it.  You can delete your own comments but not your answers.

Comment: @Tony My bad I thought it was possible. It should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Format(DateValue, "dddd, mmmm d, yyyy hh:mm AM/PM")
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you wanted a formula solution:**

Assume the following is in cell A1:

`Thursday, January 12, 2012 8:30 AM`

The following formula will extract the date portion and format it as a date:

`=DATEVALUE(MID(A1,FIND(",",A1)+1,LEN(A1)))`

This will show `40920` in the cell. Format the cell as Date to display it as a mm/dd/yyyy date (or however you want to format it).

Comment: Hello JP...its working fine..But i need "1/12/2012 8:30 am" instead of yours "1/9/12 12:00 AM" ..Thanks much for ur help :)